# I cannot render the program from the website's instruction using Cygwin terminal

Tags: cygwin, clang++

I tried to run the program from this link recently.
https://www.scratchapixel.com/code.php?id=59&origin=/lessons/advanced-rendering/rendering-distance-fields

I have also downloaded the Cygwin and installed the important steps as instructed from this website:
https://www.ics.uci.edu/~pattis/common/handouts/cygwinclion/cygwin.html

However, when I followed the coed from the website like this:

[image]

I tried two times to run and it says like this:

[image]

My files are surely saved in the directory where I want to run the Cygwin terminal but I am wondering why it is not reading my files?

[image]

Have I done something wrong?

And also, what is the meaning of these statements?

**Run with: ./distfileds. Open the file ./spheretrace.ppm in Photoshop or any program reading PPM files.**

Comment: @iBug, thank you editing the format of my images. I was trying to ad html code to appear it, but at some point, I am not allowed to do so. Thank you so much...

Comment: The syntax for image is `![description](url)`, i.e. just an extra exclamation mark before a regular link syntax.

Answer (score 0):

When you are at the Cygwin terminal, you need to use forward slashes `/` when specifying the directory path in your `cd` command.  When you use the backslash `\` character, the one at the end essentially creates a line continuation, which is why the shell is telling you `cd` has too many arguments.  Change your `cd` command as follows:

```
 cd /cygdrive/c/Users/user/Desktop/render/
```

Note that you cannot directly use `C:` as you would at the windows prompt.  You will need to check the actual directory location to make sure it is correct.  I'm guessing you will need to make some fixes there as well.

Comment: Wow! Thank you Mr. Patrick, it worked well now... :D <br/>
However, when I tried to type the commands: <br/>
$ clang++ -o distfields distfields.cpp -std=c++14 -O3<br/>

The screen says an error:<br/>


user@DESKTOP-FTJKA08 /cygdrive/c/Users/user/Desktop/render<br/>
$ clang++ -o distfields distfields.cpp -std=c++14 -O3<br/>
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -liconv<br/>
clang-5.0: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)<br/>

<br>How should I fix this?<br/>